# Linker (ld) output .img

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, linker, ld

I'm developing a mini kernel in C and Assembly.
This is my Assembly File:

```
global loader
extern main

MODULEALIGN equ 1<<0
MEMINFO equ 1<<1
FLAGS equ MODULEALIGN | MEMINFO
MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
CHECKSUM equ -(MAGIC + FLAGS)
section .text
    align 4

MultiBootHeader:
    dd MAGIC
    dd FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM

STACKSIZE equ 0x4000
loader:
    mov esp, stack+STACKSIZE
    push eax
    push ebx

call main

cli

hang:
   hlt
   jmp hang

section .bss
    align 4
stack:
    resb STACKSIZE
```

This is my C file:

```
void print(char* message, int color)
{
    char* mem = (char*)(0xb8000);
    while(*message != 0)
    {
        *mem = *message;
        mem++;
        message++;
        *mem = (char*)color;
        mem++;
    }
}
void main(void* mbd, unsigned int magic)
{
    print("Hello World\n",0x0F);
    print("Your Magic is ",0x0F);
    print(magic,0x0F);
}
```

And my Linker (.ld) file is:

```
ENTRY(loader)
SECTIONS {
    . =0x00100000;
    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }
    .rodata ALIGN (0x1000) : {
        *(.data)
    }
    .bss : {
        sbss = .;
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
        ebss = .;
    }
}
```

For Compiling the Assembler File I use

```
nasm -f elf bootloader.asm
```

when I compile the C file I use

```
gcc -m32 -o kernel.o -c kernel.c -Wall -Wextra -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs
```

and for compile `.ld` file I use

```
ld -m elf_i386 bootloader.o kernel.o -o os.img
```

but the output (`os.img`) isn't compatible with VirtualBox and QEMU. So my question is:
**How to Compile these files in a Floppy Disk Image (.img) or an ISO file**

Comment: Google "loopfs"

Comment: regarding: `*mem = *message;`  this does NOT copy the message.  Suggest: `strcpy( mem, message );`  (this is assuming that the contents of *message is a NUL terminated string.  if not, then need to know the actual length of *message and use something similar to: `memcpy( mem, message, messageLength );

Comment: Your process doesn't create a disk image. It creates an elf executable that is multiboot compliant. If you want to create an ISO with GRUB (multboot bootloader) you can use grub-mkrescue . in QEMU you should be able to laucn your kernel with the built in multiboot support with `qemu-system-i386 -kernel os.img`

Comment: I also don't see where you use a the linker script in any of the command lines you supplied. You also `call vincenzo` but there is no function by that name. Maybe you mean `call main`?

Comment: You should compile the `.c` files with the additional option `-ffreestanding` so that GCC knows it is not a hosted environment.

Comment: To use the linker script  you can do `ld -T link.ld -m elf_i386 bootloader.o kernel.o -o os.img` (where `link.ld` is whatever you called your linker script)

Comment: @user3629249 : He's not copying the string he is just copying a single byte and then incrementing the pointers after as he loops through the string.

Comment: The problem is that when I use QEMU, it give me that _core dump created_ and the process is cancelled

Comment: Were you able to resolve the problem then?

Comment: With QEMU it works, but in VirtualBox it gives me this error:VERR_NOT_SUPOORTED

Comment: Because as i said os.img is not a disk image(your file name is very misleading so isn't helping you). `os.elf` might be a better name, It is an elf executable.VirtualBox has no built in grub support. As I mentioned in an earlier comment you can crreate an ISO image with grub in it and have it run your kernel. That can be done by using `grub-mkrescue` program.

Answer (score -1):

To boot an OS from any device it also needs it's magical number which is **0xaa55**.
You should use this in your linker file too, as signature.
See Linux setup.ld file (you can see signature section.Linux uses **0x5a5aaa55**):
[setup.ld](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/setup.ld)

To compile your asm files:

```
%.bin: %.asm
      nasm $< -f bin -o $@
```

to create elf file, after -f replace bin with elf.
to create a binary of kernel:

```
kernel.bin: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
      ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -T linker.ld $^ --oformat binary
OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}
%.o: %.c
      gcc ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o $@
CFLAGS = -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32
```

to create an elf output:

```
kernel.elf: boot/kernel_entry.o ${OBJ}
          ld -m elf_i386 -o $@ -T linker.ld $^
```

at the end, to create an os binary image you can do:

```
os-image.bin: bootsect.bin kernel.bin
          cat $^ > os-image.bin
```

`bootsect.bin` is compiled file of your assembly file(entry assembly). we compiled it first.
to run in qemu you can do:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.bin
```

option -fda will run your image as a floppy disk image.

Comment: From where that `0x5a5aaa55` comes, though?